# MyMessage<T> throws an exception when calling XmlSerializer

Tags: nservicebus

I am very new to nservicebus. I am using version 3.0.1, the last one up to date. And I wonder if my case is a normal limitation of NSB, I am not aware of.

I have an asp.net MVC application, I am trying to setup and in my global.asax, I have the following :

```cs
var configure = Configure.WithWeb()
                .DefaultBuilder()  
                .ForMvc()
                .XmlSerializer();
```

But I have an error with the XmlSerializer when dealing with one of my object:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class MyMessage<T> : IMessage 
{
        public T myobject { get; set; }
}
```

I pass trough :

```cs
XmlSerializer() 
instance.Initialize(types);
this.InitType(type, moduleBuilder);
this.InitType(info2.PropertyType, moduleBuilder);
```

and then when dealing With T,

```cs
string typeName = GetTypeName(t);
```

typename is null and the following instruction :

```cs
if (!nameToType.ContainsKey(typeName))
```

ends in error. null value not allowed.

Is this some limitations to Nservicebus, or am I messing something up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus intentionally does not support generic message types to encourage you to make your message schema explicit.